# How to memoize MySQL connection client cleverly in external module used from e.g. sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mysql2

I think the question does not pin-point to the real problem, I have difficulties to nail it down precisely and concisely.

I have a gem that implements i.e. MySQL-database "queries" (also inserts, updates...)

```
module DBGEM::Query
  def self.client settings=DBGEM.settings
    @@client ||= Mysql2::Client.new settings
  end

  def query_this
    client.query(...)
  end

  def process_insert_that list_of_things
    list_of_things.each do |thing|
      # process
      client.query(...)
    end
end
```

Furthermore, this gem is used by a sinatra app sitting on a forking webserver like puma.

Within the sinatra-app i can now

```
get '/path' do
   happy = DBGEM::Query.query_this
   # process happy
   great = DBGEM::Query.process_insert_that 1..20
   # go on
end
```

I like that API and this code should open only one database connection.

But as far as I understood, because the code within the 'get' definition is not guaranteed to be the only one accessing the `DBGEM::Query` stuff at that time, weird things could happen (through race-conditions, shared internal state?).

Is there a clever way to keep the nice syntax and the connection sharing without boilerplate object creation (`query = DBGEM::Query.new() #...`) wrapping the stuff in a block (`DBGEM::Query.process do |query| #...`)?

The example above is obviously simplified. The sinatra handling might be more involved, the Queries actually done in a Service object etc.pp. Also, afaiu in a forking webserver environment, the GC would destroy the `client` (closing the connection - thats how mysql2 is implemented).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the connection will not be closed every time.

`@@client` is shared between `DBGEM::Query` object itself (in Ruby modules and classes are also objects) and all the instances of that object (to be precise: all the instances of classes to which that object is mixed in).

So, this variable will live as long as the `DBGEM::Query` object will live.

You can check out when `DBGEM::Query` object will be garbage collected, by defining finalizer logging a text and observe the server console.

```
  module DBGEM::Query
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, proc { print 'garbage collected' })
    ..
  end
```

Im not sure, however I guess that `DBGEM::Query` object will be garbage collected only when you stop the server.

As it goes for weird "things could happen", I believe you mean potential conflicts, race conditions, situations where you create double records, or update the same record nearly at the same time overwriting something, etc. And when that happen you lose data integrity.

IMHO you can't prevent it by allowing only one `client` instance. I'd suggest aiming for solid database design (unique constrains, indexes, foreign keys, validations) which can raise errors when race condition occure and then handling that errors in your application.

Comment: You define the finalizer on the module itself, not on instances of classes which include the model. Thus, it's almost sure that the finalizer will never be called.

Comment: Also by "weird things happening", what OP meant was that a single mysql2 client object is only partially suited to be used across threads and might show race-conditions (including overlapping transactions, incomplete or unexpected results, ...). While the mysql2 gem itself aims to be thread-safe, I'd be very careful here.

Comment: When it goes for the finalizer yes, because `@@client` variable lives as long as the module object (not instances objects), reference: The Well Grounded Rubyist, chapter: 5. The default object (self), scope and visibility.